# Change responseText value

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

Does anybody know if I can change the `responseText` of the ajax object so that I can make a bottleneck to all messages that uses ajax request and change them before the `responseText` is used anywhere the request come from?

I saw that `responseText` has only the getter property so Firefox don't let me change it, but I want that all income messages from my website goes through this new object and change it.

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: since the response is coming from server, can't you do whatever processing you want to do, on server side?

Comment: yes, but it's not the server side answer i'm looking to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no control over the page being called...

The ResponseText is purposely read-only (for various reasons).  Of course, you can certainly insert an intermediary JavaScript function inside any of the following events: OnSuccess, OnError and OnComplete.  This function could alter your data and respond differently based on your criteria.

**UPDATE:**
As promised, below is controller-class I use for one of my applications.  Notice the ExceptionManager contained in the USAGE area holds a copy of the PeepingTom.Controller.  Also notice the ExceptionManager is passed-into the controller (as context)...and as such...it intercepts all calls.

Of course, your classes could do a parred-down version of this.  If you want ALL you classes to use the same controller (rather than have their own instance)...you certainly could do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PeepingTom = (function($) {
        var publicInstances = {};

        // ***********************
        // Controller
        publicInstances.Controller = Controller;
        function Controller(context, processorUrl, controllerUrl) {

            // ********** PROPERTIES:  **********
            var Self = this;

            /// <summary>Represents the context-class using this instance.</summary>
            this.Context = context;
            /// <summary>Represents a handle returned from a setTimeout or setInterval call which can be used to cancel the timer.</summary>
            this.TimerHandle;
            /// <summary>Represents a wait timer until the next long-poll is executed.</summary>
            this.WaitInterval = 1000;
            /// <summary>Represents a relative path to the long-poll Processor.</summary>
            this.LongPollingProcessor = processorUrl;
            /// <summary>Represents a relative path to the long-poll Controller.</summary>
            this.LongPollingController = controllerUrl;

            // ********** METHODS **********
            /// <!-- Initialization -->
            /// <summary>Initializes the (overall) component.</summary>
            this.Initialize = function() {

                if (Self.Context.GetRequestObject)
                    Self.SetupAjax();
                else
                    alert("Context must implement 'GetRequestObject()'.");
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>Setup default values for ALL ajax requests</summary>
            /// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/"></see>
            this.SetupAjax = function() {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST'
                });
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>Makes an ajax call to the long-poll Listener.</summary>
            this.Fetch = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    complete: Self.OnComplete,
                    data: Self.Context.GetRequestObject(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: Self.OnError,
                    success: Self.OnSuccess,
                    url: Self.LongPollingProcessor
                });
            }
            /// <summary>Logs a message to the console.</summary>
            this.Log = function(message) {
                if (console)
                    console.log(message);
            }

            // ********** EVENTS **********
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>A function called when the request finishes.</summary>
            /// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/"></see>
            /// <param name="xmlHttpRequest">The XMLHttpRequest object.</param>
            /// <param name="status">A string containing the success or error code.</param>
            this.OnComplete = function(xmlHttpRequest, status) {
                if (Self.Context.OnComplete)
                    Self.Context.OnComplete(xmlHttpRequest, status);
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>Setup default values for ALL ajax requests</summary>
            /// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/"></see>
            /// <param name="xmlHttpRequest">The XMLHttpRequest itself (object).</param>
            /// <param name="status">A string describing the type of error that occurred</param>
            /// <param name="error">The exception object (optional).</param>
            this.OnError = function(xmlHttpRequest, status, error) {
                if (Self.Context.OnError)
                    Self.Context.OnError(xmlHttpRequest, status, error);

                Self.Log("OnError - " + error);
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>(optional) Actions to take when the session becomes invalid.</summary>
            /// <see>OnSuccess: data.SessionValid = false</see>
            this.OnSessionExpired = function(data) {
                if (Self.Context.OnSessionExpired)
                    Self.Context.OnSessionExpired(data);

                if (data) {
                    if (data.Exception) {
                        Self.Log("InnerException - OnError: " + data.Exception.InnerException);
                        Self.Log("Message - OnError: " + data.Exception.Message);
                        Self.Log("Source - OnError: " + data.Exception.Source);
                        Self.Log("StackTrace - OnError: " + data.Exception.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>A function to be called if the request succeeds.</summary>
            /// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/"></see>
            /// <param name="data">The data returned from the server (formatted according to the 'dataType' parameter).</param>
            /// <param name="status">A string describing the status.</param>
            /// <param name="xmlHttpRequest">The XMLHttpRequest object (available as of jQuery 1.4).</param>
            this.OnSuccess = function(data, status, xmlHttpRequest) {
                if (data == null) {
                    Self.OnSessionExpired(data);
                }
                else {
                    if (!data.SessionValid) {
                        Self.OnSessionExpired(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (Self.Context.OnSuccess)
                            Self.Context.OnSuccess(data, status, xmlHttpRequest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ***********************
        // Utility
        publicInstances.Utility = Utility;
        function Utility() {

            // ********** PROPERTIES:  **********
            var Self = this;

            // ********** METHODS **********
            /// <summary>Creates a new GUID</summary>
            /// <remarks>This operational method is useful in creating unique Id's.</remarks>
            this.CreateGuid = function() {
                var result, i, j;
                result = '';
                for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                    if (j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20)
                        result = result + '-';
                    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
                    result = result + i;
                }
                return result;
            }
            /// <summary>Converts a milli-second formatted-date into a normalized date format.</summary>
            this.ConvertDateFromMilliSeconds = function(text) {
                var match;
                if (!(match = text.match(/\d+/)))
                    return "";

                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(match[0] - 0);

                return date;
            }
            /// <summary>Converts a date to UTC time.</summary>
            this.ConvertUTCtoLocalTimeZone = function(date) {
                // creates a Date in local time
                var realDate = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));

                // converts the Date to UTC by adding or subtracting the time zone offset
                var offsetMilliseconds = realDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
                realDate.setTime(realDate.getTime() - offsetMilliseconds);
                date = realDate.toLocaleString();

                return date;
            }
            /// <summary>Converts a UTC date to a short-date (mm/dd/yyyy).</summary>
            this.ConvertUTCtoShortDate = function(utcDate) {
                var month = utcDate.getUTCMonth();
                var day = utcDate.getUTCDay();
                var year = utcDate.getUTCFullYear();

                return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            }

            // ********** EVENTS **********
        }

        return publicInstances;
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**USAGE:**
Here is a copy of an Exception Manager that uses the Controller (above)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ExceptionManager = (function($) {
        var publicInstances = {};

        // ***********************
        // Observer
        publicInstances.Observer = Observer;
        function Observer(userControlId, asOf) {

            // ********** PROPERTIES **********
            var Self = this;

            /// <summary>Controls long-polling communications.</summary>
            this.Controller = null;
            /// <summary>Represents a utility class-instance.</summary>
            this.Utility = null;
            /// <summary>Represents the Viewer object.</summary>
            this.Viewer = null;

            /// <summary>The TEMPLATE ID used in creating an observation.</summary>
            this.TemplateId = "#template-exceptionManager-Exception";

            /// <summary>Represents a collection of observation objects.</summary>
            this.Observations = null;
            /// <summary>Used to pause processing of observations.</summary>
            this.Pause = false;
            /// <summary>Alters the speed with which observations are processed.</summary>
            this.PauseInterval = 2000;
            /// <summary>Determines how long to wait until the next long-poll is executed.</summary>
            this.WaitInterval = 2000;

            /// <summary>The design-time Id of this user-control instance.</summary>
            this.UserControlId = userControlId;
            /// <summary>The datetime stamp used in determining which observations to gather-up.</summary>
            this.AsOf = asOf;
            /// <summary>The ID of the last observation in the current batch.</summary>
            this.LastId = 0;

            /// <summary>The relative path of the long-polling processor.</summary>
            this.ProcessorUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Handlers/ActivityExceptionProcessor.ashx")%>';
            /// <summary>The relative path of the long-polling controller.</summary>
            this.ControllerUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Handlers/ActivityExceptionController.ashx")%>';

            // ********** METHODS **********
            /// <!-- Initialization -->
            /// <summary>Initializes the Observer.</summary>
            this.Initialize = function() {

                // Find the activityViewer within the document (the object that manages the display-queue)
                if ((activityViewer != null) && (activityViewer.IsInitialized)) {
                    Self.Controller = new PeepingTom.Controller(Self, Self.ProcessorUrl, Self.ControllerUrl);
                    Self.Controller.WaitInterval = Self.WaitInterval;
                    Self.Utility = new PeepingTom.Utility();
                    Self.Observations = new Array;      // THIS objects queue of observations.
                    Self.Viewer = activityViewer;
                    Self.InitializeQueue();             // THIS objects queue of observations.
                    Self.Controller.Fetch();
                }
                else
                    setTimeout(Self.Initialize, 2000);  // Every 2 seconds
            }
            /// <!-- Initialization -->
            /// <summary>Initializes the queue that processes Observations.</summary>
            this.InitializeQueue = function() {
                if (!Self.Pause) {
                    if (Self.Observations.length > 0) {
                        var observation = Self.Observations.pop();
                        Self.AppendObservation(observation);
                    }
                    setTimeout(Self.InitializeQueue, Self.PauseInterval);
                }
            }
            /// <summary>Enqueue's this observer's newly found Observations.</summary>
            this.Enqueue = function(observations) {

                if ($(observations).length > 0) {

                    var lastItem = $(observations).last();
                    Self.LastId = lastItem[0].Id;

                    $(observations).each(function() {
                        // Append dynamic properties
                        this.TemplateId = Self.TemplateId;
                        // Append dynamic events
                        this.OnProcessed = function() { Self.OnProcessed(this); };
                        Self.Viewer.Enqueue(this);
                    });
                }
            }
            /// <summary>Returns a populated XMLHttpRequest object.</summary>
            this.GetRequestObject = function() {
                var request = { UserControlId: Self.UserControlId, AsOf: Self.AsOf };
                return request;
            }

            // ********** EVENTS **********
            /// <!-- Notification -->
            /// <summary>Notifies this control when an observation is processed.</summary>
            this.OnProcessed = function(observation) {
                if (observation.Id == Self.LastId) {
                    Self.Controller.TimerHandle = setTimeout(function() { Self.Controller.Fetch(); }, Self.WaitInterval);
                }
            }

            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>A function called when the request finishes.</summary>
            /// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/"></see>
            /// <param name="xmlHttpRequest">The XMLHttpRequest object.</param>
            /// <param name="status">A string containing the success or error code.</param>
            this.OnComplete = function(xmlHttpRequest, status) {
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>Setup default values for ALL ajax requests</summary>
            /// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/"></see>
            /// <param name="xmlHttpRequest">The XMLHttpRequest itself (object).</param>
            /// <param name="status">A string describing the type of error that occurred</param>
            /// <param name="error">The exception object (optional).</param>
            this.OnError = function(xmlHttpRequest, status, error) {
                Self.Controller.Log("ExceptionManager - OnError: " + error);
                alert("ExceptionManager - OnError");
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>(optional) Actions to take when the session becomes invalid.</summary>
            /// <see>OnSuccess: data.SessionValid = false</see>
            this.OnSessionExpired = function(data) {
                Self.Controller.Log("ExceptionManager - OnSessionExpired");
                alert("ExceptionManager - OnSessionExpired");
            }
            /// <!-- Communication -->
            /// <summary>A function to be called if the request succeeds.</summary>
            /// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/"></see>
            /// <param name="data">The data returned from the server (formatted according to the 'dataType' parameter).</param>
            /// <param name="status">A string describing the status.</param>
            /// <param name="xmlHttpRequest">The XMLHttpRequest object (available as of jQuery 1.4).</param>
            this.OnSuccess = function(data, status, xmlHttpRequest) {
                Self.AsOf = data.AsOf;
                if (data.Observations) {
                    if (data.Observations.length > 0)
                        Self.Enqueue(data.Observations);
                    else
                        Self.Controller.TimerHandle = setTimeout(function() { Self.Controller.Fetch(); }, Self.WaitInterval);
                }
            }
        }

        return publicInstances;
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: sure, but this only works for one ajax request.. i was looking to change the response of the response of any request on the page. For example from the server side prints "hello world" and i want to change the it to "Server: hello world", not for just 1 call... is like an ajax sniffer with a bootleneck for all responseText.

Comment: If you point every call to the same controller class...this will work.  In fact, it's exactly what I do.  I will post a sample above in a moment.